# Error when trying to convert C# code to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I'm converting some C# code from another project to VB.Net but the following code is throwing an error

```
Dim obj As System.Collections.ArrayList()
obj = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StreamReader("../sample.htm",encoding.Default),
styles)
```

The error is 'Value of type Systems.Collections.Generic.List() cannot be converted to 'Systems.Collections.Arraylist()'

The original C# code is

```
System.Collections.ArrayList obj;
obj = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StreamReader("../sample.htm",Encoding.Default),
styles);
```

What would be the correct VB code?

Comment: You don't need (= shouldn't use) the `()` after ArrayList. Parenthesis are also used to declare arrays in VB, and this could lead to confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this has nothing to do with C#/VB. It appears to me that

- for your C# code, you used an earlier version of your library which returned an ArrayList and
- for your VB code, you used a newer version that returned a generic list.

The simplest solution is to use type inference:

```
// C#
var obj = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StreamReader("../sample.htm", Encoding.Default), styles);

'' VB 
Dim obj = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StreamReader("../sample.htm", Encoding.Default), styles)
```

Note that to use this you need to have "Option Infer" set to "On" in your project properties.

If you don't want to use type inference, you need to declare `obj` with the correct type. To determine the correct type, either look up the documentation of `ParseToList` or read the information provided by IntelliSense when you type `HTMLWorker.ParseToList(`. For example, if ParseToList returns a generic List of `IElement`s, the correct syntax is:

```
Dim obj As Systems.Collections.Generic.List(Of IElement)
obj = ...
```